# Merge in list from another list that are not present in the former list

Tags: java

The two list have different structure. The list originalPgs is a list of `PGRatingConfig` and has this structure:

```
class PGRatingConfig {
....
    Rating rating; 
}

class Rating {
  String pgId;
  String value;
}
```

pgLookupTable returns List which is of the form: id and name of the product

```
private List<PGRatingConfig> addendumPgs(List<PGRatingConfig> originalPgs) {
        List<Rating> ratings = pgLookupTable();
        List<String> pgIds = ratings.stream().map(a -> a.getPgId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(PGRatingConfig rating: new ArrayList<>(originalPgs) ){
            for(Rating ratingObj: new ArrayList<>(rating.getRating())){
                for(String pg: pgIds){
                    if(!rating.getRating().stream().map(r->r.getPgId()).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(pg)){
                        rating.getRating().add(new Rating(pg, 3.0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        log.info("originalPgs, "+originalPgs);
        return originalPgs;
    }
```

How do I improve this code? I had to cycle between Java 8 and pre-8 code just to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

For starters you should stop putting stream operations on a single line. They should be formatted so that each stream operation is on their own line. It makes following the code much easier:

```
if (! rating.getRating()
    .stream()
    .map(r->r.getPgId())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .contains(pg)) {
    rating.getRating().add(new Rating(pg, 3.0));
}
```

Secondly, collecting the results to see if the result contains a single value is unnecessary waste. Especially if oyu use a List instead of `Collectors.toSet()` The same as above can be achieved with filtering and finding a match:

```
if (! rating.getRating()
    .stream()
    .filter(r -> pg.equals(r.getPgId()))
    .findAny()
    .isPresent() {
    rating.getRating().add(new Rating(pg, 3.0));
}
```

You are not modifying the `originalPgs` collection, only the objects in it, so there is no need to create new `ArrayList` for it. The inner loop that uses the `ratingObj` variable is unnecessary, because you are not using `ratingObj` anywhere in your code.

```
for (PGRatingConfig rating: originalPgs) {
    for (String pg: pgIds) {
        if (! rating.getRating()
            .stream()
            .filter(r -> pg.equals(r.getPgId()))
            .findFirst()
            .isPresent() {
            rating.getRating().add(new Rating(pg, 3.0));
        }
    }
}
```

Now there probably is a way to do this without the inner loop that iterates over `pgIds` but I don't have the time to explore it now.

Answer (score 2):

None of this is going to be directly helpful because we don't have enough visibility into the surrounding code, and it's not clear to what extent you can make changes. It looks like the overall codebase has some severe challenges which you may not have the ability to change.

This code is very hard to read because the names of various things are not at all helpful.

- `pgLookupTable()` is a method that returns a `List`, where the reader would expect a `Map` or some other kind of lookup structure.
- `getRating` is singular, but apparently returns a `List<Rating>`? > `PGRatingConfig`, `pgId`, etc. are totally obtuse because `PG` is meaningless. > `addendumPgs` is confusing because `addendum` does not mean anything close to what this method does.
- calling a `PGRatingConfig` a `rating` means the code can't use `rating` later, when there is an actual rating.
- a `pgId` should not be stored in a variable named `pg`.

Why does a rating take a double value and store it as a String? That's confusing at best.

I've downvoted this question because `PGRatingConfig` doesn't provide the methods that `addendumPgs` clearly expects.

The `ratings` property is used only once, on the very next line. Fold it into the stream call.

In idiomatic java, there is whitespace between `for` and `(`, and also between `)` and `{`

Since the lists are not modified, there's no point in defensive copies unless the code is in a multithreaded environment, which I doubt given what the rest of the code looks like. Both instances of `new ArrayList<>` can be removed.

The code is looping over the Ratings in each `PGRatingConfig` and then not doing anything with the value it's looping over. This `for` loop appears to be doing nothing except repeating the inner `for` loop to no benefit.

The stream collecting pgIds should be computed once, not once for every pgId. Since it's being used to check for existence, it should be stored in a `Set` for O(1) lookup, instead of a `List` with O(n) lookup.

It would be preferable to hide the `Ratings` collection from clients of `PGRatingConfig` and only expose methods that clients care about, such as `addRating()`.

`PGRatingConfig` should probably store the Ratings as a `Map<Long /* PgId */, Rating>`.

Depending on the codebase, the code could also compute the disjoint ids directly in PgRatingConfig. Or, if the code must expose the collection, it can compute the missing IDs in `addendumPgs`.

If you made all these changes, your code might look something like:

```
private List<PGRatingConfig> addendumPgs(List<PGRatingConfig> originalPgRatingConfigs) {
    List<String> pgIds = pgLookupTable().stream().map(a -> a.getPgId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (PGRatingConfig pgRatingConfig: originalPgRatingConfigs) {
        for (String pgId: pgIds) {
            if (!pgRatingConfig.hasRatingWithPgId(pgId)) {
                pgRatingConfig.addRating(new Rating(pgId, "3.0"));
            }
        }
    }
    return originalPgRatingConfigs;
}

private List<PGRatingConfig> addMissingPgs(List<PGRatingConfig> originalPgRatingConfigs) {
    List<String> pgIds = pgLookupTable().stream().map(a -> a.getPgId()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (PGRatingConfig pgRatingConfig: originalPgRatingConfigs) {
        for (String missingPgId: pgRatingConfig.findMissingPgIds(pgIds)) {
            pgRatingConfig.addRating(new Rating(missingPgId, "3.0"));
        }
    }
    return originalPgRatingConfigs;
}

class PGRatingConfig {
    private Map<String, Rating> ratings;

    public Map<String, Rating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public boolean hasRatingWithPgId(String pgId) {
        return ratings.containsKey(pgId);
    }

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        ratings.put(rating.getPgId(), rating);
    }

    public Set<String> findMissingPgIds(Collection<String> pgIds) {
        Set<String> missingPgIds = new HashSet<>(pgIds);
        missingPgIds.removeAll(ratings.keySet());
        return missingPgIds;
    }
}

class Rating {
    private String pgId;
    private String value;

    public Rating(String pg, String value) {
        this.pgId = pg;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getPgId() {
        return pgId;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public List<Rating> pgLookupTable() {
    return null;
}
```

If you absolutely can't change any code other than the method you provided, I think the best you can do is:

```
private List<PGRatingConfig> addendumPgs2(List<PGRatingConfig> originalPgs) {
    Set<String> pgIds = pgLookupTable().stream().map(a -> a.getPgId()).collect(toSet());

    for (PGRatingConfig pgRatingConfig: originalPgs) {
        Set<Rating> missingRatings =
                pgRatingConfig
                    .getRating()
                    .stream()
                    .map(rating -> rating.getPgId())
                    .filter(id -> !pgIds.contains(id))
                    .map(id -> new Rating(id, 3.0))
                    .collect(toSet());
        pgRatingConfig.getRating().addAll(missingRatings);
    }

    log.info("originalPgs, "+originalPgs);
    return originalPgs;
}
```